# How would you say "put aside the exceptions"?

Tags: phrases

In Hungarian we say "eltekintünk a kivételektől" which means that we don't care about the exceptions when we create our model of sthg. Now I don't know how should I say this in English. I thought that maybe "put aside the exceptions" would be a good translation, but I haven't found anything like that in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can say, "*Ignoring any exceptions,...*" or "*Putting aside any exceptions,...*" or "*If you pay no attention to exceptions,...*".

(Or even "*Modulo any exceptions,...*", though that is kind of informal math-geek-speak.)

Answer (score 2):

I love words and grammar and as a personal curse I find foreign languages rather interesting. Hungarian is an extremely difficult language for primarily English speakers' to learn. You had to completely reverse your sentence structures and meanings. Once those are rearranged.... we can have a hard time painting our depth.

*That being said I must give you a few contextual examples 
which may give you the power and meaning 
you're wanting to convert into English. 
  All are merely suggestions from a truly passionate lover of language.*

Put your notions aside, We dont care about the exceptions when we create our model of stgh!

*Push your notions aside*

We don't care about your preconceived notions when we create our model of stgh!

When we create models of Stgh we do so exemption free!

We are free from exempt *or* Exemptions when create our STGH.

Your ideals don't infringe upon our system of beliefs!

> Notion: A pre conception or type of self fufilling prophecy so to seek. But a negative notion is one which is used upon you.
>
> http://www.dictionary.com/browse/exception
>
> > ex·emp·tion
> >     the process of freeing or state of being free from an obligation or liability imposed on others.
> >     "exemption from prescription charges"
> >     synonyms:   immunity, exception, dispensation, indemnity, exclusion, freedom, release, relief, absolution
> >
> > > > the process of exempting a person from paying taxes on a specified amount of income for themselves and their dependents.
> > > >
> > > > > US
> > > > >           an item or amount exempted.
> > > > >           "a series of exemptions from the partnership tax rules"
> > > > >           Translate exemption to
> > > > >           noun
> > > > >           1. felmentés
> > > > >           2. kiváltság
> > > > >           https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS780US780&q=exemption&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB76WY0J3bAhWH7IMKHWKOCMwQBQgkKAA&biw=1366&bih=662